# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns nil even after creating cell instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to use a UITableView with a .xib file. I have done it in the past with storyboards, where you declare a reuse id in a dynamic prototype. I have this code inside the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` function which should work:

```
NSString *ReuseId = @"DefaultCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReuseId];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell == nil");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:ReuseId];
}
```

However, when I run this, instead of printing `cell == nil` once it prints it for every row.

Why??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time when you open table view there will be no cells to reuse because all of them will be actually in use. Cells start being reused when you start scrolling the table and some cells start disappearing from the top.

**update**

Let's say you have a table view that can partially display 6 rows (5.5 by height). When UITableViewController loads the table with the cells, it creates 6 cell instances because all of them must be displayed at the same time.

When you start scrolling and the first cell is hidden, it gets added to reusable cell set. That's when creating 8th cell (because 7th will be created newly, 'cause 1st one will still be visible by half height) the first one will be reused.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear: because a TableViewController can hold about 12 cells, it will only start to reuse the cells after I scroll down to the 13th and then back up to the top?

Comment: no. because 11 or 12 fit on the screen, fully or partly. The tableview will only create enough cells that they fit on the screen while scrolling.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. Let me rephrase: Does the cell in the second row get reused or only cells not visible when the table view first loads?

Comment: @cabellicar123 The second cell is a new cell the first time it loads.  If you scroll down on the tableview, and then back up, it may reused.  The number of cells allocated is usually the number of cells you can see.

Answer (score 4):

How many rows do you have? It should create up to to 11 or 12 at first on iPhone. Depending on the height of the tableview and the heights of the cells.

So if you have less rows than cells fit on the view, cell reuse will never happen and is not needed.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell == nil");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:ReuseId];
} else {
    NSLog(@"We have a reused cell!");
}
```

try to repeat your rows several times and scroll slowly. Now every time you are just about to scroll the first pixel of a new cell on the view, it should print "We have a reused cell!".